# Open xml SDK. The picture can't be displayed when I insert it

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I just started working with Open Xml SDK and I have the following problem. I am trying to replace a text with an image in a word file using Open xml SDK. 
The image is on the desired spot but I get the icon " the picture can't be displayed". If I add the image to the end of the document everything works OK. Why is that?

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc1 = WordprocessingDocument.Open(link, true))
{
    Text textPlaceHolder = wordDoc1.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>().Where((x) => x.Text == "(Imageplaceholder)").FirstOrDefault();
    if (textPlaceHolder == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text holder not found!");
    }
    else
    {
        var parent = textPlaceHolder.Parent;

        if (!(parent is Run))  // Parent should be a run element.
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Parent is not run");
        }
        else
        {
            var element =
        new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing(
            new DW.Inline(
                new DW.Extent() { Cx = 480000L, Cy = 792000L },
                new DW.EffectExtent()
                {
                    LeftEdge = 980000L,
                    TopEdge = 0L,
                    RightEdge = 0L,
                    BottomEdge = 0L
                },
                new DW.DocProperties()
                {
                    Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                    Name = "Picture 1"
                },
                new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                    new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                new A.Graphic(
                    new A.GraphicData(
                        new PIC.Picture(
                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                {
                                    Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                    Name = "Test.jpg"
                                },
                                new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                            new PIC.BlipFill(new A.Blip(
                                    new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                        new A.BlipExtension()
                                        {
                                            Uri =
                                            "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                        })
                                )
                                {
                                    Embed = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Test.jpg",
                                    CompressionState =
                                  A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                },
                                new A.Stretch(
                                    new A.FillRectangle())),
                            new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                new A.Transform2D(
                                    new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                    new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                new A.PresetGeometry(
                                    new A.AdjustValueList()
                                )
                                { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                    )
                    { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
            )
            {
                DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
                EditId = "50D07946"
            });

            // Insert image (the image created with your function) after text place holder.        
            textPlaceHolder.Parent.InsertAfter<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing>(element, textPlaceHolder);
            // Remove text place holder.
            textPlaceHolder.Remove();
            wordDoc1.Close();
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your `using` block (within the { } ):

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc1 = WordprocessingDocument.Open(link, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

    ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        imagePart.FeedData(stream);
    }
    var relationshipId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);

    # And then continue with the code you had:
    Text textPlaceHolder = wordDoc1.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Text>().Where((x) => x.Text == "(Imageplaceholder)").FirstOrDefault();
    # etc
```

Then replace your line

```
Embed = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Test.jpg",
```

with

```
Embed = relationshipId,
```

**For future reference:**

For me the problem was that I was writing the document to a file before I had disposed of the `WordprocessingDocument` object.

Either wrap `WordprocessingDocument` in a `using` block (like the OP does) or call `wordprocessingDocument.Dispose()` before you write the document stream to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You've put a path in the *Embed* property, but it should be the ID of an image part. You'll find how to create this part at the same [MSDN URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx) you've copied the rest from.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)